# SQL: Move column data to other table in same relation

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm wondering if it's possible to move all data from one column in table to another table.
Here's what i'm trying to do:

Table 1 : users - columns trying to read+move = oauth_access_key and oauth_access_secret

Table 2 : account_users - target columns: oauth_token_key, oauth_token_secret

The relation key between these tables is "user_id".

Is this possible in one query? I know this is easily done in PHP, but i'm wondering if this can be done in plain SQL.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: update w/join OR insert/select

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
UPDATE users, account_users 
SET account_users.oauth_token_key=users.oauth_access_key,  
    account_users.oauth_token_secret = users.oauth_access_secret
WHERE account_users.user_id=users.user_id;
```

You can use `JOIN` syntax on [MySQL Update](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html).

Comment: Doesnt this just copy the table row to the new place but still leave the previous column in the same original table?

Answer (score 10):

I think the answer you are looking for is

```
INSERT INTO `account_users` (`user_id`, `oauth_token_key`, `oauth_token_secret`)
SELECT `user_id`, `oauth_access_key`, `oauth_access_secret` FROM `user`
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
  `oauth_token_key` = VALUES(`oauth_token_key`),
  `oauth_token_secret` = VALUES(`oauth_token_secret`);
```

#### EDIT

I am assuming you want to move data as in 'put it somewhere it hasn't been yet'.

#### EDIT2

Here is a documentation on `VALUES()`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_values

Comment: I think that might work :) I'm currently importing my database to a testing environment so I don't screw things up. I'll let you know if it worked in a few mins. Thanks for the quick response! 

#edit: actually, the records in account_users already exist. Only the columns the data need to go don't have data yet.

Would something like this work?:

Comment: If you want to use this query multiple times, you might want to extend the query to update the values on already existing rows. See @PtPazuzu his answer on how to do that. ;)

Comment: UPDATE `account_users`,`users` SET `account_users`.`oauth_token_key`=`users`.`oauth_access_key` WHERE `users`.`id`=`account_users`.`user_id`

Comment: Yes, that part. I might update my answer though to be complete. Don't forget the 'secret' part of your table though ;)

Comment: I updated my answer. The final SQL inserts the rows that don't exist and updates the existing ones.

Answer (score 5):

Since the title is SQL, and not DB specific... here's a solution for those who stumble upon this while searching for **Postgres**:

```
UPDATE account_users        
SET oauth_token_key = users.oauth_access_key,  
    oauth_token_secret = users.oauth_access_secret
FROM profiles
WHERE account_users.user_id = users.user_id;
```

Comment: Where did `profiles` come from?

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO account_users (user_id, oauth_token_secret) 
SELECT users.user_id, users.oauth_access_secret FROM users 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE account_users.oauth_token_secret = users.oauth_access_secret
```