# MySQL move whole columns between tables

Tags: php, mysql, hash

the situation is: I have two tables, `Data1` and a new table `Data2`. 
The `Data1` table has two columns, `users` and `hashes`, that store the login information of each user.
The `Data2` table has the columns `Nicks`, `hashes`, `last_login`, `registration_date`, and a few more

How could the data from `Data1` be copied into the `Nicks` and `hashes` columns of the `Data2` table?
Assuming they are both the same type, nicks and users, and hashes and hashes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL: Move column data to other table in same relation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856849/sql-move-column-data-to-other-table-in-same-relation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO Data2(`Nicks`, `hashes`)
SELECT `users`, `hashes` FROM Data1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO Data2 (Nicks, Hashes)
SELECT (users, hashes)
From Data1;
```

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp